# unable to revoke android subscription

Tags: android

I am trying to revoke a subscription using:

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/purchases/subscriptions/subscriptionId/tokens/token:revoke POST API

Every time I try to revoke, I get the following error message,

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

I am pretty sure that the package name, subscription id and token are correct since if I send wrong values to those, I get a different error message. Please help.

Comment: Can you do the request "manually" to verify the subscription ID and token are correct? What code are you using to make the request?

Comment: Its a Internal Server Error.

Comment: Actually I am sending the post request manually. I have not coded anything yet

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Not sure if this is because it's a test subscription, but regardless, this is a bad behavior.

Comment: @Eugene Try cancelling the subscription. That's what I ended up doing.

Comment: @hackphone that works just for testing expiration, yes, but for testing application logic where I actually want to revoke someone's sub, I can't actually do a valid end-to-end test in a sandbox environment which is pretty bogus IMO.