# How to test android subscription

Tags: android

I am trying to test subscription using android. I am able to purchase a subscription. After purchasing when I try to purchase the subscription again, I get an error 'you already own this item' till the subscription period expires. For development and testing purposes, I need to purchase the subscription often.

I read the docs and found that I can test by revoking the subscription. I tried revoking the subscription, but that doesn't happen and it throws error. I have created a question for that [unable to revoke android subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504924/unable-to-revoke-android-subscription?noredirect=1#comment49085295_30504924)

Can someone suggest a different strategy for testing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You've probably found your answer already, since it's been 4 months you've asked. But...

After you've tested the subscription purchase itself and you know that your app can communicate properly with Google's API, you should start using mock purchases to test your app's behaviour when there is an active subscription and when there's not.

In my app, for example, I have an option (that exists only in my debug builds) that allows me to go through the purchase flow without actually purchasing anything (not even a test subscription) and making my app think that the purchase completed normally (or failed, when I want to test how my app behaves when something goes wrong).